# Compile less file after dynamic load

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, less

I have less file for every component in my website. I import every component with it's styles and controls. I want to compile less file after I load it.

how html looks like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" href="./signin/signin.less">
<div class="signin">
   //content
</div>
<script type="module" src="./signin/signin.js"></script>
```

After I load the files I write this JavaScript line but it never works

```
less.refreshStyles();
```

any one can help?!

Answer (score 0):

Okay I tried many less functions and none of them worked. I was writing them in the `main.js` file. So I moved the commands to the script that gets loaded with the less files and it worked under these commands:

```
less.registerStylesheets();
less.refresh();
```

In short:

instead of writing code in `main.js` I wrote them in `signin.js`